# Select from two overloaded methods

Tags: c++, null, overloading, visual-studio-6

There is a class with two similar constructors...

```
class CX
{
public:
    CX(HEADER header,
              __int64    i64Id); 

    CX(HEADER  header,
              const char* pszName);
    // other methods...
};
```

I want to call the second constructor with null pointer.

```
CX *data1 = new CX(&header, NULL); 
//it is ambiguous call to overloaded function

CX *data2 = new CX(&header, (const char*)NULL); 
// is correct, but against our coding standards...

CX *data3 = new CX(&header, static_cast<const char*>(NULL));
// is correct, but agains our coding standards...

const char* pszName = NULL;
CX *data4 = new CX(&header, pszName);
// this is correct but waste of stack.
```

Is there any better way how to select the constructor?
(nullptr would be the solution in this case, but it's not possible because it should be compilable in VC6)

Comment: What does your coding standard permit? `#define NULLCHARPTR ((const char*)0)` maybe?

Comment: Seems your coding standards are very restrictive.  Your last solution is the only other possible solution.  If you make pszName's type `const char* const` then the compiler will most likely optimise it out.

Comment: If you can use c++11, use `nullptr`.

Comment: `CX data = new CX` is Java stye, not C++. So guess what I think about your coding standards...

Comment: Oh, that was my mistake. I wasn't copy'n'paste-ing the code but typing directly. The define is the nicest solution.

Comment: @V-X No it's not. The problem is your coding standard that dissallows `static_cast` where it's perfectly applicable.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify 2nd constructor taking NULL as default argument and call it passing first argument as only argument

CX(HEADER  header,
              const char* pszName=NULL);

Comment: Unfortunately. I am not allowed to change the class.

Comment: In that case, please add "not to use NULL" in your coding standard so that classes are not designed in such a manner :D